# Getting value out of json using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have following json text:

```
    "data": [
        {
            "Id": "abc",
            "Indexes": {
                "Status": 0,
            }
        },
        {
            "Id": "bcd",
            "Indexes": {
                "Status": 1,
            }
        }

]
```

I am trying to get Id where status = 0. 
I can get this using for loop like:

```
 for id in test['data']:
        if data['Indexes']['Status'] == 0:
            id = id["Id"]
```

But is there a better one-liner way of doing this?

Comment: `data` is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some problems with used variables in your code. This should work:

```
for data in test['data']:
    if data['Indexes']['Status'] == 0:
        # do something with data["Id"]
```

If you only want to get the first such item:

```
this_id = next(data["Id"] for data in test["data"] if data["Indexes"]["Status"] == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension over `test['data']`:

```
results = [id['Id'] for id in test['data'] if id['Indexes']['Status'] == 0]

# results contains every such id
```

And if you want only the last match in the list of ids, such as your code seems to do, reverse `test['data']` and get the `next` from a iterator made from that:

```
last_result = next(id['Id'] for id in reversed(test['data']) if id['Indexes']['Status'] == 0)

# last_result is the last matching id
```